# wordpress Live site redirect to localhost

Tags: wordpress

I have develop a site (word press) locally and move it in to a remote server. Everything seems fine except when I click the home link it redirect to my localhost website.

To fix this what I did was,
Changed the site url and home url to web url without adding the slash after the url.

Apart from that I added the following code to wp_config.php

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://mysite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://mysite.com');
```

But when click the home button it still redirect in to the localsite.

I have changed wp_option table also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to update the url given in menu navigation for Home button.

Answer (score 10):

you need to change url into database too

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace (option_value , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 
      'http://www.newsite.com')         
   WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace 
   (guid , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace 
       (post_content , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com');


UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace 
    (meta_value , 'http://www.oldsite.com' , 'http://www.newsite.com');
```

Comment: have you used page or something in url?

Comment: This worked for me along with a cache clear that was cause a redirect to the live https. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In  wp_options table change siteurl option value to your live site url.
If still problem exists search 'localhost' in your db and replace it with live site url.

Answer (score 0):

Update wp_options table in database for siteurl and home. In the table first row is siteurl and 36th row is home.

Comment: I read what I missed or where I did wrong please could you tell me. However have you fixed issue? You should check in theme's code that, is there written any hardcoded link.

Comment: I have mention that I updated the table and I have given the answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing `wp_options` table worked. Had to make sure to clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that 99% of web developers work on localhost and then deploy to somewhere that is obviously NOT localhost. It really annoys be that this sort of error happens. How much time is wasted by not having a live vs dev setting for this? Mine is still insisting on going to localhost. I'm going to have to search my HDD for the word localhost at this stage
Finally found it under General Settings - Site Address URL which does not correspond to what is in wp_options.